# JQuery and CSS Tab General Insight

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I downloaded the jQuery sample "tab demo" page. It includes the HTML file, 3 CSS files, and two JS files.

When I review the HTML file, I see several references to id(#) tags (ex. #tab, #tabs-1, #tabs-2, etc.) BUT when I look (manually and using "search:) in the support CSS and JS files, I see NO id being defined? I see lots of classes (.) but no ids that match.

Explain to me how this is working? My goal of course was to find the id #tab so I could manipulate its size, color, font, etc.

This is at the bottom of the page… I believe this is the key. Is this replacing the IDs with the CLASSES and if so - why?

```
<script> $( "#tabs" ).tabs(); </script>
```

Comment: Can you post what code you have?

Comment: http://www.lc4d.com/student_support/jq_tabs.html

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the code in question

Comment: The id tags aren't being used for styling.  They are used in the javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>tabs demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style>
.tabs_addition{
    min-height:500px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs" class="tabs_addition">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="fragment-1">
    <p>First tab is active by default:</p>
    <pre><code>$( "#tabs" ).tabs(); </code></pre>
  </div>
  <div id="fragment-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
  <div id="fragment-3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So this is the source code of the html page. What the js code does is call the tabs method defined in the jquery ui to add all these extra classes to the #tabs divs and all the elements within it so that the css defined by the jquery ui can format your html to looks like the demo.

Now you want to "skin" it. You can just define your style like this:

```
#fragment-1 {background-color: #ff9900; font-size: 20px; color: #ffff00;}
#fragment-2 {background-color: #333333; font-size: 22px; color: #ff5555;}
#fragment-3 {background-color: green; font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff;}
```

As for not using id to style stuff, I don't think it really matters. Keep in mind that id is unqiue and class can be used however time you want. If you have common styles, then use a class selector. If it's unique to this element, then you can go ahead and use an id.

Comment: So you're suggesting I leave all the QU and originl CSS intact- and simply add the new #fragment ids to my page to skins. So just leave the original JQ/CSS files alone?

Comment: Yeah, you should always leave the jquery ui library alone. You can overwrite it with your css in your own css file that you can append after your include the library css files.